# Save outputs of nested for loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have the following codes which I wish to have an output matrix Rpp of (10201,3). I run this code (which takes a bit long) then I check the matrix size of Rpp and I see (1,3), I tried so many things I couldn't find any proper way. The logic of the codes is to take the 6 values (contain 4 constant values and 2 variable values (chosen from 101 values)) and make the calculation for 3 different i1 and store every output vector of 3 in a matrix with (101*101 (pairs of those 2 variable values)) rows and 3 (for each i1) columns.

I appreciate your help

```
    Vp1=linspace(3000,3500,101);
    Vp2=3850;
    rho1=2390;
    rho2=2510;
    Vs1=linspace(1250,1750,101);
    Vs2=2000;
    i1=[10 25 40];


    Rpp = zeros(length(Vp1)*length(Vs1),length (i1));

    for n=1:length(Vp1)*length(Vs1)
    for m=1:length (i1)
    for l=1:length(Vp1)
        for k=1:length(Vs1)


           p=sin(i1)/Vp1(l);
           i2=asin(p*Vp2);
           j1=asin(p*Vs1(k));
           j2=asin(p*Vs2);
           a=rho2*(1-2*Vs2^2*p.^2)-rho1*(1-2*Vs1(k).^2*p.^2);
           b=rho2*(1-2*Vs2^2*p.^2)+2*rho1*Vs1(k)^2*p.^2;
           c=rho1*(1-2*Vs1(k)^2*p.^2)+2*rho2*Vs2^2*p.^2;
           d=2*(rho2*Vs2^2-rho1*Vs1(k)^2);
           E=b.*cos(i1)./Vp1(l)+c.*cos(i2)/Vp2;
           F=b.*cos(j1)./Vs1(k)+c.*cos(j2)/Vs2;
           G=a-d*(cos(i1)/Vp1(l)).*(cos(j2)/Vs2);
           H=a-d*(cos(i2)/Vp2).*(cos(j1)/Vs1(k));
           D=E.*F+G.*H.*p.^2;
           Rpp=((b.*(cos(i1)/Vp1(l))-c.*cos((i2)/Vp2)).*F-(a+d*((cos(i1)/Vp1(l))).*(cos(j2)/Vs2)).*H.*p.^2)./D
        end
    end
    end
    end
```

Comment: What are your 2 outer `for` loops suppose to be for.  I don't see you using the vars `n` or `m` inside the loop...???  Also whatever it is your calculating you just keep overwriting Rpp on each iteration.  IT won't append on its own.  You should be doing something like Rpp(index,:) = .... probably were `index` is some kind of counter. `index = 1` outside of loop and `index = index+1` inside of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use the for loop is wrong. You're running the calculation for `length(Vp1)*length(Vs1)` *  `length (i1)` * `length(Vp1)` * `length(Vs1)` times. Here's the correct way. I changed `l` into `lll` just so I won't confuse it with the number 1. In each iteration of the first for loop, you're running `length(Vs1)` times, and you need to assign the result (a 1X3 array) to the `Rpp` by using a row number specified by `k+(lll-1)*length(Vp1)`.

```
for lll=1:length(Vp1)
    for k=1:length(Vs1)
       p=sin(i1)/Vp1(lll);
       i2=asin(p*Vp2);
       j1=asin(p*Vs1(k));
       j2=asin(p*Vs2);
       a=rho2*(1-2*Vs2^2*p.^2)-rho1*(1-2*Vs1(k).^2*p.^2);
       b=rho2*(1-2*Vs2^2*p.^2)+2*rho1*Vs1(k)^2*p.^2;
       c=rho1*(1-2*Vs1(k)^2*p.^2)+2*rho2*Vs2^2*p.^2;
       d=2*(rho2*Vs2^2-rho1*Vs1(k)^2);
       E=b.*cos(i1)./Vp1(lll)+c.*cos(i2)/Vp2;
       F=b.*cos(j1)./Vs1(k)+c.*cos(j2)/Vs2;
       G=a-d*(cos(i1)/Vp1(lll)).*(cos(j2)/Vs2);
       H=a-d*(cos(i2)/Vp2).*(cos(j1)/Vs1(k));
       D=E.*F+G.*H.*p.^2;
       Rpp(k+(lll-1)*length(Vp1),:)=((b.*(cos(i1)/Vp1(lll))-c.*cos((i2)/Vp2)).*F-(a+d*((cos(i1)/Vp1(lll))).*(cos(j2)/Vs2)).*H.*p.^2)./D;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I felt there were serious problems inside, but I couldn't diagnose them.

Comment: What do you mean? My code should work exactly like the other answer..(then of course you need to add the part before the for loop..) I just left out `index` and use loop variable `k` and `lll` for counting and to illustrate how loop counting works.

Comment: I mean it wasn't working before, it's fine after I made the changes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  You 2 outer loops didn't do anything.  You never used `m` or `n` so I killed those 2 loops.  Also you just kept overwriting `Rpp` on every loop so your initialization of `Rpp` didn't do anything.  I added an `index` var to assign the results to the equation to what I think is the correct part of Rpp.

```
Vp1=linspace(3000,3500,101);
Vp2=3850;
rho1=2390;
rho2=2510;
Vs1=linspace(1250,1750,101);
Vs2=2000;
i1=[10 25 40];
Rpp = zeros(length(Vp1)*length(Vs1),length (i1));
index = 1;
for l=1:length(Vp1)
    for k=1:length(Vs1)    

        p=sin(i1)/Vp1(l);
        i2=asin(p*Vp2);
        j1=asin(p*Vs1(k));
        j2=asin(p*Vs2);
        a=rho2*(1-2*Vs2^2*p.^2)-rho1*(1-2*Vs1(k).^2*p.^2);
        b=rho2*(1-2*Vs2^2*p.^2)+2*rho1*Vs1(k)^2*p.^2;
        c=rho1*(1-2*Vs1(k)^2*p.^2)+2*rho2*Vs2^2*p.^2;
        d=2*(rho2*Vs2^2-rho1*Vs1(k)^2);
        E=b.*cos(i1)./Vp1(l)+c.*cos(i2)/Vp2;
        F=b.*cos(j1)./Vs1(k)+c.*cos(j2)/Vs2;
        G=a-d*(cos(i1)/Vp1(l)).*(cos(j2)/Vs2);
        H=a-d*(cos(i2)/Vp2).*(cos(j1)/Vs1(k));
        D=E.*F+G.*H.*p.^2;
        Rpp(index,:)=((b.*(cos(i1)/Vp1(l))-c.*cos((i2)/Vp2)).*F-(a+d*((cos(i1)/Vp1(l))).*(cos(j2)/Vs2)).*H.*p.^2)./D;
        index = index+1;
    end
end
```

Results:

```
>> size(Rpp)

ans =

       10201           3
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked the way I wanted it to be look like

Comment: If it works for you please accept the answer so it doesn't hang out on the site as an unanswered questions.